# C++ Taylor series and Trig table

Tags: c++, taylor-series

Okay so I am creating a program that outputs the cosine, sin, and other trig values all in a single table for angles 0 through 360 in increments in 15. As part of the assignment we are required to show both the system cosine and system sine using the given sin and cos commands within C++, as well as the sine and cosine values calculated using a taylor series. My error in my program comes about when I calculate the sine and cosine values using a taylor series. I  commented out some of the code so hopefully that will make it easier to view. Any and all suggestions would be appreciated. Also I will post a sample output of the program as it stands.

```
 Angle  Sys Cos   Cosine  Sys Sin    Sine  Tangent   Cotangent   Secant Cosecant

     0   1.0000   1.0000   0.0000   0.0000   0.0000      inf
    15   0.9659   0.0341   0.2588  -0.9659  -0.9659     -inf
    30   0.8660   0.1340   0.5000  -0.8660  -0.8660     -inf
    45   0.7071   0.2929   0.7071  -0.7071  -0.7071     -inf
    60   0.5000   0.5000   0.8660  -0.5000  -0.5000     -inf
    75   0.2588   0.7412   0.9659  -0.2588  -0.2588     -inf
    90   0.0000   1.0000   1.0000   0.0000   0.0000     -inf
   105  -0.2588   1.2588   0.9659   0.2588   0.2588     -inf
   120  -0.5000   1.5000   0.8660   0.5000   0.5000     -inf
   135  -0.7071   1.7071   0.7071   0.7071   0.7071     -inf
   150  -0.8660   1.8660   0.5000   0.8660   0.8660     -inf
   165  -0.9659   1.9659   0.2588   0.9659   0.9659     -inf
   180  -1.0000   2.0000   0.0000   1.0000   1.0000     -inf
   195  -0.9659   1.9659  -0.2588   0.9659   0.9659     -inf
   210  -0.8660   1.8660  -0.5000   0.8660   0.8660     -inf
   225  -0.7071   1.7071  -0.7071   0.7071   0.7071     -inf
   240  -0.5000   1.5000  -0.8660   0.5000   0.5000     -inf
   255  -0.2588   1.2588  -0.9659   0.2588   0.2588     -inf
   270  -0.0000   1.0000  -1.0000  -0.0000  -0.0000     -inf
   285   0.2588   0.7412  -0.9659  -0.2588  -0.2588     -inf
   300   0.5000   0.5000  -0.8660  -0.5000  -0.5000     -inf
   315   0.7071   0.2929  -0.7071  -0.7071  -0.7071     -inf
   330   0.8660   0.1340  -0.5000  -0.8660  -0.8660     -inf
   345   0.9659   0.0341  -0.2588  -0.9659  -0.9659     -inf
   360   1.0000  -0.0000  -0.0000  -1.0000  -1.0000   0.9501

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.044 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

// Function Prototypes..
//  These are the only function you need to write
//      See Sample functions below main()
double Factorial(double);   // For loop version
double Sine(double);        // Taylor Series Sine
double Cosine(double);      // Taylor Series Cosine
double Tangent(double);     // Tangent(x) = Sine(x)/Cosine(x)
double Cotangent(double);   // Cotangent(x) = Cosine(x)/Sine(x)
double Secant(double);      // Secant(x) = 1.0/Cosine(x)
double Cosecant(double);    // Cosecant(x) = 1.0/Sine(x)

void PrintTrigTable(void);  // Print Trignometric Table


// This main function is complete
int main()
{
    PrintTrigTable();

    return 0;
}

// PrintTrigTable - write this function
void PrintTrigTable()
{
cout << fixed<<setw(6)<<"Angle";
cout <<fixed << setw(9) << "Sys Cos" << setw(9) << "Cosine" << setw(9) << "Sys Sin" << setw(8) << "Sine";
cout << fixed << setw(9) << "Tangent" << setw(12) << "Cotangent" << setw(9) << "Secant" << setw(9) << "Cosecant" <<endl;
for (double x = 0.0; x <= 360.0; x += 15.0)

{

    cout << fixed << setw (6) << setprecision(0) << x;

    cout << fixed << setw (9) << setprecision(4)<< cos(x*3.1415926/180);

    cout << fixed << setw (9) << setprecision(4)<< Cosine(x);

    cout << fixed << setw (9) << setprecision(4)<< sin(x*3.1415926/180);

    cout << fixed << setw (9) << setprecision(4)<< Sine(x);

    cout << fixed << setw (9) << setprecision(4)<< Tangent(x);

    cout << fixed << setw (9) << setprecision(4)<< Cotangent(x) <<endl;

    //cout << fixed << setw (9) << setprecision(4)<< Secant(x)<<endl;

    //cout << fixed << setw (9) << setprecision(4)<< Cosecant(x) <<endl;

}
}
// Factorial - write this function
double Factorail(double angle)
{
double fact = 1;
for (double i =1; i <= angle; i++)
fact *=i;
return(fact);
}

// Sine - write this function
double Sine(double angle)
{
double PI = 3.1415926;
double mysin= 0, mysin2= 9999;
double anglerad = angle*PI/180.0;
 double  c =1., counter, fact;
while (abs(mysin2-mysin)> .0001)
{

     mysin2= mysin;
     fact = 1;
    for ( double k =1; k <= counter; k++)
    fact *=k;
    mysin= mysin + pow(-1,c)*(pow(anglerad,counter)/fact);
    c = c+1;
    counter = counter +2;

}
return(mysin);
}

double Cosine(double angle)
{
double PI = 3.1415926;
double mycos= 1, mycos2= 9999;
double anglerad = angle*PI/180.0;
double c =1, counter, fact;
while (abs(mycos2-mycos)> .0001)
{

     mycos2= mycos;
     fact = 1;
    for ( double k =1; k <= counter; k++)
    fact *=k;
    mycos= mycos + pow(-1,c)*(pow(anglerad,counter)/fact);
    c = c+1;
    counter = counter +2;

}
return(mycos);
}
// Tangent - Tangent(x) = Sine(x)/Cosine(x)
double Tangent(double angle)
{
    double inf = (Sine(angle)/Cosine(angle));
    if (inf > 100)
    {
        inf =1.0/0.0;
    }
    else if (inf < -100)
    {
        inf = -1.0/0.0;
    }
    return inf;
}

// Cotangent - write this function -
double Cotangent(double angle)
{
    double inf = (Cosine(angle)/Sine( angle));
    if (inf > 100)
    {
        inf =1.0/0.0;
    }
    else if (inf < -100)
    {
        inf = -1.0/0.0;
    }
    return inf;
}

// Secant - Secant(x) = 1.0/Cosine(x)
double Secant(double angle)
{
    double inf = (1.0/Cosine(angle));
    if (inf > 100)
    {
        inf =1.0/0.0;
    }
    else if (inf < -100)
    {
        inf = -1.0/0.0;
    }
    return inf;
}

// Cosecant - write this function
double Cosecant(double angle)
{
   double inf = (1.0/Sine(angle));
    if (inf > 100)
    {
        inf =1.0/0.0;
    }
    else if (inf < -100)
    {
        inf = -1.0/0.0;
    }
    return inf;
}
```

Comment: what is your issue? any error or any unexpected result?

Comment: There is no error but if you look at the sample output the system cosine, and Cosine should have equal values. As well as the Sys Sine and Sine values. There is an error in my math somewhere within the Sine and Cosine taylor series.

Comment: I just fixed my cosine portion of the code, the mycos value should have been at 0 instead of 1. Also the sine in between my cos +  pow(-1,c) needed to be changed to a -. Still stuck on the sine issue though

Comment: Mathematically, once you've got a working `sin` (or `cos`), you can calculate all the others using trig identities. In other words, unless you're explicitly required to do so, it's better not to use (similar but not identical) Taylor series for each of the calculations; just use `sin(x) = cos(x - pi)` etc.

Comment: I am required for the assignment to do it this way or I would use a simple shortcut as suggested. Sorry if i did not make that clear.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are built-in constants you can use for some of these values so you don't have to define them yourself. You can use `M_PI` for the value of pi, and you can use `FLT_MAX` when you want the largest floating point value as a starting value (instead of `9999` in this case).

Comment: I notice you aren't initializing the `counter` variable. You just start using it, so it's value could be invalid. And shouldn't you be using your implementation of `Factorial()` (which you've misspelled) rather than copying the code into each other function?